# Filter by empty value inside column Django object

Tags: django

How do I filter by just empty value? I can do this:

```
Name.objects.filter(alias__isnull=False)
```

But it will not work because it's just empty inside the column with no value. How can I filter by that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question you want all Name objects, except ones where alias is None or ''. You can do that with: `Name.objects.filter(alias__isnull=False).exclude(alias__exact='')`